# Crear una fecha y hora aleatoria dentro del mismo mes natural

Tags: php, sql, date, random

Estoy buscando la manera de implementar una funcion en PHP que me genere unaa fecha aleatoria ej: 
2020-04-25 18:45

La cosa es que me gustaria que fuese teniendo en cuenta siempre el mes natural en el que estamos, de manera que si ejecuto la funcion en Mayo, me genere una cita en Mayo.. luego ya veria como acotar un horario tambien.

La verdad que no se me ocurre como hacer para que sea en el mes natural.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Puedes generar una timestamp UNIX (un entero) y convertirla a `DATE` en SQL.

El timestamp UNIX cuenta los segundos desde el 01/01/1970.

Por ejemplo: **1587427200** es igual a 21/04/2020 @ 00:00:00 hrs

Y para convertirlo:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + ([Numero generado]/24/60/60) as fecha;
```

Puedes verificar tus rangos deseados con un Excel o [una herramienta online](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).